# Only add conditional formatting if it does not exist yet

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I add conditional formatting to the Excel file:

```
Sub Apply_Conditional_Formatting()
With Tabelle1.Range("=$1:$1048576")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=$F$1"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End With
End Sub
```

This code is linked to a button in the sheet the user can push often as he wants.
Every time the the button is clicked the conditional formatting is added to the sheet which makes the menu look like this:
[image]
*(Sorry for only having it available in German)*

Is there a way to check if the conditional formatting already exists so it is not added?

Comment: Why do you want to reapply it? The point of conditional formatting is that you apply it once when you design the sheet.

Comment: See [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition): If a range has multiple formats, you can use the **Modify** method to change one of the formats, or *you can use the **Delete** method to delete a format, and then use the **Add** method to create a new format.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to check if there is *any* conditional formatting is set on the sheet:

```
With Sheet1.Cells
    If .FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=$F$1"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End If
end with
```

If you want to check explicitly for the formula (because the sheet may contain other conditional formatting), use something like this

```
With Sheet1.Cells
    Dim fc As FormatCondition, found As Boolean
    For Each fc In .FormatConditions
        If fc.Formula1 = "=$A1=$F$1" Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next fc

    If Not found Then
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=$F$1"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End If
End With
```

(replace `Sheet1` with the sheet you want to work with)